# Keras: Concatenate multiple outputs into a final output in image segmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I am currently working on an image segmentation project using the power of neural networks.
The purpose is to segment cracks present on the roads.

I first used a Unet network. And I get correct results.

While doing research I came across several scientific articles that deal with the same subject.

In this paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/328649776_DeepCrack_Learning_Hierarchical_Convolutional_Features_for_Crack_Detection

they use this architecture:

[image]

It is a segnet based architecture. Except that between each encoder / decoder "level" there is an intermediate image output with its own loss.
At the end of the network the 5 images are concatenated and there will be a single image as output.

This is an exemple of all intermediate images:

[image]

The model was coded in caffee and the code is not available (at least I did not find it)

I tried to implement this architecture in Keras

And this is what I got for now (I only show the concatening part, otherwise it would be too long):

```
# CONCATENATE
# S1
concat_1 = concatenate([b5, b6])
conv_1 = Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu')(concat_1)
deconv_1 = Deconv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(32, 32), strides=(16, 16), padding='same')(conv_1)
scale_1 = Activation(activation='sigmoid', name='scale_1')(deconv_1)

# S2
concat_2 = concatenate([b4, b7])
conv_2 = Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu')(concat_2)
deconv_2 = Deconv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(16, 16), strides=(8, 8), padding='same')(conv_2)
scale_2 = Activation(activation='sigmoid', name='scale_2')(deconv_2)

# S3
concat_3 = concatenate([b3, b8])
conv_3 = Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu')(concat_3)
deconv_3 = Deconv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(8, 8), strides=(4, 4), padding='same')(conv_3)
scale_3 = Activation(activation='sigmoid', name='scale_3')(deconv_3)

# S4
concat_4 = concatenate([b2, b9])
conv_4 = Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu')(concat_4)
deconv_4 = Deconv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(4, 4), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(conv_4)
scale_4 = Activation(activation='sigmoid', name='scale_4')(deconv_4)

# S5
concat_5 = concatenate([b1, b10])
conv_5 = Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu')(concat_5)
deconv_5 = Deconv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(1, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(conv_5)
scale_5 = Activation(activation='sigmoid', name='scale_5')(deconv_5)

# FINAL CONCATENATE
final_concate = concatenate([deconv_1, deconv_2, deconv_3, deconv_4, deconv_5])
final_conv = Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='sigmoid', name='final_output')(
    final_concate)

model = Model(inputs, outputs=[scale_1, scale_2, scale_3, scale_4, scale_5, final_conv])
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(),
              loss={'scale_1': 'binary_crossentropy',
                    'scale_2': 'binary_crossentropy',
                    'scale_3': 'binary_crossentropy',
                    'scale_4': 'binary_crossentropy',
                    'scale_5': 'binary_crossentropy',
                    'final_output': 'binary_crossentropy'}
              , loss_weights={'scale_1': 0.1,
                              'scale_2': 0.2,
                              'scale_3': 0.4,
                              'scale_4': 0.8,
                              'scale_5': 1.0,
                              'final_output': 1.0}
              , metrics={'final_output': 'accuracy'})
model.summary()

return model
```

So I have 5 intermediate output and a final output.

Therefore I need 6 training data-set. But as the intermediate images must be as close as possible to the final image I will therefore naively used the same training data-set for the 6 outputs.

Like this:

```
y_train = {
    "scale_1": y_train,
    "scale_2": y_train,
    "scale_3": y_train,
    "scale_4": y_train,
    "scale_5": y_train,
    "final_output": y_train
}

y_test = {
    "scale_1": y_test,
    "scale_2": y_test,
    "scale_3": y_test,
    "scale_4": y_test,
    "scale_5": y_test,
    "final_output": y_test
}
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=10, validation_data=[X_test, y_test])
```

But the problem is that I don't get any results during training. Each loss is negative.
I use cross entropy for each output.

Maybe I'm not doing it right. Or that this type of network cannot be implemented in Keras

Do you have suggestions ?

I realize that this is a big question and that it may not be suitable for stack overflow format. I will delete it if necessary.

Comment: you can try https://github.com/pierluigiferrari/caffe_weight_converter and there is a pytorch implementation https://github.com/yhlleo/DeepSegmentor

Comment: I'll take a look at it. Thank you